# How to get values from BigQuery nested Record type

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BQ table that has a column of type `RECORD` that looks like this:

```
tags
 |_ sub_tags
```

When I do:

```
SELECT tags.sub_tags FROM `MY_TABLE`
```

I get this:

| Row | sub_tags.array_element |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | :something |
|  | :something_else |
|  | what::the:hell |
| 2 | more_stuff |
| 3 | and_more_stuff |

How do I get the value or check if `:something` exists in the `STRUCT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if these solutions help: given that you have a struct in your source table with tags.sub_tags .

```
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT struct(['one', 'two','three'] AS sub_tags) as tags 
  union all 
  SELECT struct(['one', 'four','three'] AS sub_tags) as tags 

) 
SELECT * FROM `yourTable` 
where 'two' in unnest(tags.sub_tags) 

SELECT * except(value) FROM `yourTable`, unnest(tags.sub_tags) as value 
where value = 'two'
```

These are some good reference for arrays:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays

Answer (score 1):

Use below simple approach

```
select *
from your_table
where contains_substr(tags.sub_tags, ':something')
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

While this solution applicable for your specific simple case  - solution provided by Pratik can cover more complex scenarious